# How/where to format INSERT statement by aligning columns with values

Tags: sql, insert, format

I would like to know how I can format the INSERT statement from:

```
INSERT tablename ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5]) VALUES (2,1,11,NULL,4), (2,1,11,NULL,4), (2,1,11,NULL,4);
```

to:

```
INSERT tablename ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5]) 
          VALUES (        2,         1,        11,      NULL,         4),
                 (        2,         1,        11,      NULL,         4),
                 (        2,         1,        11,      NULL,         4);
```

Do you know some text formatter that do it?

I found several options, but none that do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't discover an existent solution, so  I do it with PHP.

Let me know about any questions,

Enjoy!

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback("/(INSERT)\s+(.+)\s+\((.+)\)\s+(VALUES)\s+\((.+)\);*/", function($matches) {
    $columns = explode(",", $matches[3]);
    $values  = explode(",", $matches[5]);

    //length of INSERT + tablename
    $length = strlen("$matches[1] $matches[2]");
    //fills VALUES with leading spaces
    $values_with_spaces = str_pad($matches[4], $length, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $newColumns = $newValues = [];
    foreach($columns as $key => $column) {
        $value = !isset($values[$key]) ? 'NULL' : $values[$key];

        //takes the longest length between the column and the value
        $column_length = max(strlen($column), strlen($value));

        $newColumns[$key] = str_pad($column, $column_length, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $newValues[$key]  = str_pad($value, $column_length, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return "$matches[1] $matches[2] (".join(",",$newColumns).")\n$values_with_spaces (".join(",",$newValues).");\n";
}, file_get_contents("php://stdin"));
```